# c++ code to check if an integer contains a given hexadecimal pattern

Tags: c++, hex

I have some integers (64-bit) which I want to check contain some hexadecimal patterns.

For example, let's say the integer is 0x00000B21, and I want to check whether it contains the *hexadecimal* pattern 0x00000A20. If I do the normal `(Num1 & Num2) == Num2`, this will check whether the `Num1` contains the *binary* pattern `Num2`. (In the example I cited this will return true, even though hexadecimally the numbers don't match.)

What's a good way to check for hexadecimal patterns?

Comment: `&&` is a logical AND, `&` is a bitwise AND.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What exactly do you mean by "contains the pattern"? And if the bit pattern matches in hexadecimal, it will match in binary as well.

Comment: @AusCBloke : Thanks for pointing that out. It was a typo.

Comment: @DanielPryden : true, but the converse is not. A binary match does not imply a hexadecimal match.

Comment: For example the binary pattern `1011` contains the binary pattern `0010` but the hexadecimal `0xB` does not contain `0x2`

Comment: @Ken: so you're saying `1011` *contains* `0010` if you treat them as bit sets? I guess that makes sense. But I still don't understand what "contains" means in the context of hexadecimal. Is it just a matter of the string representation having at least one character in common, or is it something more complex?

Comment: @DanielPryden: It seems that "contains" means that all non-zero digits of a pattern must be found in the correct positions of a hexadecimal string (e.g. `0xA21` contains `0xA20`, but `0xB21` does not). @apoorv020: I'm pretty confident in this, but could you please clarify if my interpretation is correct?

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde: yes your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @apoorv020: For future reference, the next time you ask a question, it would be helpful if you could specify the behavior you want, the way Ken Wayne VanderLinde did here.  The more precise your language, the easier it will be for others to come up with a solution that meets your needs.

Answer (score 9):

You'd do `(0x00000B21 & 0x00000FFF) == 0x00000A20`.

Basically, when you are computing the mask, for each nybble, put F if you are interested in the value, and 0 if you are not interested.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there might be a more elegant way, but this would certainly work:

```
(Num1 & Mask(Num2)) == Num2
```

where we've defined Mask as:

```
uint64 Mask(uint64 x) {
  return 
    ((x & 0xF0000000) ? 0xF0000000 : 0) |
    ((x & 0x0F000000) ? 0x0F000000 : 0) |
    ((x & 0x00F00000) ? 0x00F00000 : 0) |
    ((x & 0x000F0000) ? 0x000F0000 : 0) |
    ((x & 0x0000F000) ? 0x0000F000 : 0) |
    ((x & 0x00000F00) ? 0x00000F00 : 0) |
    ((x & 0x000000F0) ? 0x000000F0 : 0) |
    ((x & 0x0000000F) ? 0x0000000F : 0);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if 0 is a required digit within the target pattern.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do what you're wanting and avoid the problem you're talking about is to simply mask out the hexadecimal digits you don't want (the size of your pattern), and then compare that to your pattern. ie:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
   unsigned num1 = 0x00000B21;
   unsigned num2 = 0xABC0A20;
   unsigned pattern = 0xA20;

   std::cout << ((num1 & 0xFFF) == pattern) << std::endl;
   std::cout << ((num2 & 0xFFF) == pattern) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

This *will* also work when you want 0 to be included in the pattern.

Comment: This is a binary comparison, not a hexadecimal comparison. If you looks at the question, this is exactly what the OP said *doesn't* work (aside from the initial typo of a `&&` instead of `&`).

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde: How won't it work? `num1 & 0xFFF` is `0xB21`, `0xB21 == 0xA20` is 0/false. `num2 & 0xFFF` is `0xA20`, `0xA20 == 0xA20` is 1/true. The OP tried `(num & pattern) == pattern` as opposed to `(num & mask) == pattern`.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde: No worries, you had me second-guessing myself for a minute. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have first to compute the "mask" with something like

```
unsigned long long mask = 0;
while (mask < num2) mask = (mask << 4) | 0x0F;
if ( (num1 & mask) == num2 ) ...
```

The mask computation can be probably speeded up a bit by using a dichotomic approach.

Note that this check will be about finding if the hex digits of `num2` are **at the end** of `num1`. This is not the same as what `((num1 & num2) == num2)` does in binary.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a bitwise mask (Num1 & Num2) == Num2. I think this is the preferred way to do this. Computationally fast and easy to read.

Comment: As I said in the question, this will not work. Will update the question to make it more clear.

Comment: It definitely won't work with logical AND, it will work with bitwise AND.

Comment: @nmjohn: It doesn't even work with bitwise AND. The example which apoorv020 gave is a clear example of this: I don't see `0xA20` showing up in `0xB21`

Comment: I guess I don't know what the real question is still. 0xA20 => 1010 0010 0000, 0xB21 => 1011 0010 0000. That pattern 0xA20 does in fact show up in 0xB21. Maybe if we can get a few more cases (positives and negatives). this will make sense.

Comment: I believe he means on a nybble-by-nybble basis. You're right that it's not very clear though.

Comment: @nmjohn: As you point out, the binary `1011 0010 0000` contains the pattern `1010 0010 0000` because we have `1`'s showing up in the right places. But as hexadecimal patterns, `0xB21` does not contain `0xA20`, since `0xB21` doesn't have an `A` as it's third digit. However, `0xA21` *does* contain `0xA20` since there is an `A` in the third position, and a `2` in the second.

Comment: I guess the phrase "show up" should be redefined to something more precise.

Answer (score 0):

```
long number = ...;
long pattern = ...;
for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    if( ( (number >> i) & pattern) == pattern)
    {
        // true
        break;
    }
}
// false
```

This should work. Sorry if this isn't quite typical (or compilable) C++ code. I mainly write in Java.
It gets the point across, anyway.